# Scroll to specific div on page load

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I'm trying to figure out how get the page automaticlly scroll to a specific div when the page has loaded. I have tried using the jQuery scroll function, but cant get it to work correctly.
Any suggestions?

Following is what i have tried so far:

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery('.container').offset().top);
});
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can do this using the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#what').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

- This will smooth scroll to the div with ID `what`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPGPw/)

Comment: Could this be done dynamically? I would like to send the div's name in a query string like: show.aspx?divToScrollTo=SecondDiv.

Comment: Sure, it can be done. Just get the div id from query string and on page load pass it to above code like: `$('#' + divToScrollTo).offset().top`, where `divToScrollTo` is js variable where we have stored the query string value.

Comment: I would add that if you're not entirely satisfied with the final position, you can add (goes lower) or subtract (goes higher) a number of pixels you want to move it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ 
        scrollTop: $('.sb-menu').offset().top 
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Firsts you have to call the file,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Here the id is 'scroll'.
The following code is helpful:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#scroll').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="scroll"></div>

</body>
</html>
```