# Simple Javascript DOES not work as intended

Tags: javascript

why it is not alert the "window is loaded" message... it does successfully the window.location but after nothing..
Maybe the problem is that I cannot have document ready and window.load on the same function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdownbLong').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = "index.php?s=wiki_exp";
        $(window).load(function() {
            alert("window is loaded");
            $(".ss").slideToggle(2500);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this *redirect to a new page*?:  `window.location = "index.php?s=wiki_exp";`

Comment: window.location actually does a redirect so the code after the redirection is unreachable.

Comment: @Konstantinos: Then you have to do that on *the new page*.  When a page loads all of the JavaScript resets for the new page.  Think of it as closing a JavaScript application and opening another one.  Code from a closed application isn't running.

Comment: Once you do `window.location` your browser has already moved onto another page, and `.ss` ceases to exist.

Comment: @Konstantinos: The `#test` tells it to go to an `a` with the name `test`.  You can also achieve similar functionality with JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103534/scroll-to-specific-div-on-page-load  But these things are all on the page that's being opened, not the page being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the page being properly loading or the dom not ready, it's purely that you're going to a whole new page and incorrectly thinking that you're able to do things with it still.

Your script is changing the page with `window.location`. Immediately after that line, the page changes and your script stops running. There's nothing else you can do on this page that would affect the other, after you change the window's location.