# js for redirecting page on condition

Tags: javascript, php, html

I think having searched, sorry if my question has already been answered.

My website static HP (/index.html) is divided into sections:

## info, #bib, #cat ...

and sofar, not to display an empty page, it redirects to the #info section like this:

```
<body onload="window.location.href = 'index.html#info';">
```

I'd very much need the redirection to happen *only* when visitors come from another site.

I mean, i can set links in other pages pointing to the #cat or #bib sections, but like this only the #info section shall display.

Is that possible? How can i get it?
Thanks in advance
A.

Comment: if they are redirecting from another site then you dont even have to land in this page right? you can directly give link to your `index.html#bib` ..

Comment: thanks for responding. i'd like to pass to the internet the index.html link but it shows an empty page. I'd need the #bib #cat sections to work from my or other sites, but anyway those liks are bounced to #info

Comment: cant you pass the link like `index.html#bib` to the other sites? Like why should anybody land in this page which is anyways going to redirect to another page? instead make sure they go to the final page itself..

Comment: the page is the same. but jst index.html gives an almost emtpy page. index.html#anything does not,

Comment: you have control on the other site where you have your links right?

Comment: Then you can just add a script which will scroll you to the content where the element with id `bib` is..

Comment: thanks i'll try. just checkin http_referrer samples

Comment: may be this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/18103556/2592042

Comment: TY, a good hint. Maybe this page too:
https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SVR3.html

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in php might help you. Do you want to redirect to a particular link when it comes from some other website or link?

If so, above mentioned solution will work.

Comment: thanks for answering. I'll look into the php. Idea is, if someone comes to the HP from anywhere , it should give the main info.

Comment: thanks for answering. I'll look into the php.
Idea is, if someone comes to the HP from anywhere , it should give the main info.
but if one is browsing the site, it should point the the correct section. likewise if somebody bookmarks a page different from the HP.

Comment: @KamalAgrawal in the original question you don't see a `tag` with `php` in it. So it is not sure if the question poster uses `php` or not. It will be better if you confirm the details and then answer. Else the community tends to downvote your answers. Just giving you information :)

Comment: Ok, just checked, PHP sould be installed on the webs server.
I'll look into it.
the pseudo code should be st like this:
if (come from another domain) then
    goto #info
else
   goto (/ or link-asked)
endif
thank you